What is the connection of a partial regression plot and a partial dependence plot?
We have a partial regression plot as defined here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_regression_plot
It's usefulness is discussed in What does an Added Variable Plot (Partial Regression Plot) explain in a multiple regression? and essentially it allows to see the effect of a feature even when it is correlated with other features.
Now there is also the concept of a partial dependence plot https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/partial_dependence.html
This seems useful when we want to look at a treatment which is randomized (not related to other features => the partial dependence plot allows to investigate the average treatment effect: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7597863/ )
It seems to me that the partial regression plot is an extension (accounting for correlated features) of the partial dependence plot. Unfortunately, I did not find explicit literature. Could somebody confirm this connection or highlight important differences?
In a setting where a treatment would not be assigned at random (i.e. not in a randomized study) could I obtain the average treatment effect through looking at the partial regression plot?
